# Bad redirect url Google

Tags: asp.net-core

I Guys!

I have a problem with redirect to Google Login Page. I use RazorPages in my project and I have some issue... This is my Login.cshtml code:

```
@model LoginModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Log in";
    Layout = "~/Areas/Identity/Pages/_AuthLayout.cshtml";
}

<div class="col-md-10 offset-md-1">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <section>
                <div class="login-form-icon">
                    <i class="fas fa-user-circle fa-9x text-secondary text-center"></i>
                </div>
                <form id="account" method="post" asp-page-handler="LoginAsync">
                    <div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label asp-for="Input.Email"></label>
                        <input asp-for="Input.Email" class="form-control" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="Input.Email" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label asp-for="Input.Password"></label>
                        <input asp-for="Input.Password" class="form-control" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="Input.Password" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <label asp-for="Input.RememberMe">
                                <input asp-for="Input.RememberMe" />
                                @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Input.RememberMe)
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Zaloguj</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </section>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <h3>Zaloguj się przez:</h3>
            @{
                if (Model.ExternalLogins.Count == 0)
                {
                    <div>Brak możliwości zalogowania przez serwisy zewnętrzne.</div>
                }
                else
                {
                    <form method="post"
                          asp-page-handler="ExternalLogin"
                          asp-route-returnUrl="@Model.ReturnUrl">
                          <div>
                              @foreach (var provider in @Model.ExternalLogins)
                              {
                                  <button type="submit" 
                                          class="btn btn-primary" 
                                          name="provider" 
                                          value="@provider.Name" 
                                          title="Zaloguj się za pomocą konta 
                                          @provider.DisplayName">
                                      @provider.DisplayName
                                  </button>
                              }
                          </div>
                    </form>
                }
            }
        </div>
    </div>
    
</div>

    @section Scripts {
        <partial name="_ValidationScriptsPartial" />
    }
```

And this is method from my Login.cshtml.cs

```
        {
            foreach (var cookie in Request.Cookies.Keys)
            {
                Response.Cookies.Delete(cookie);
            }

            var redirectUrl = Url.Page("ExternalLogin", ReturnUrl = returnUrl);
            var properties = _signInManager.ConfigureExternalAuthenticationProperties(provider, redirectUrl);
            return new ChallengeResult(provider, properties);
        }
```

I want to redirect to Google Login Page, but when i excetuted this method - nothing happened... My redirectUrl: "/Identity/Account/ExternalLogin?handler=%2F", provider: "Google", returnUrl "/"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My redirectUrl: "/Identity/Account/ExternalLogin?handler=%2F", provider: "Google", returnUrl "/"

You can try to use following code to generate redirectUrl.

```
var redirectUrl = Url.Page("ExternalLogin", pageHandler: "Callback", values: new { returnUrl });
```